# How do I customize a Wordpress theme header to change layout?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, themes, customization

I am using the latest version of the Avada theme. I would like to place full-width content (a simple shortcode) in the header area of a page that has sidebars enabled. However, I have found that the theme does not allow you to have full-width content (aside from built-in options like the slide, menu, artwork, etc.), with a page that has sidebars enabled.

A moderator on their user forum wrote this in regards to this limitation:

> Going by your screenshot you will have to create a custom solution for that. (referring to the full width section above the page and sidebar content, based on your screenshot) – that would mean creating a std page in WP and then in the header file using PHP to call that page and it's content into position:

```
    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { $subPageHeader = new WP_Query("page_id=25″); >while($subPageHeader->have_posts()) : $subPageHeader->the_post(); ?>
```

> This is just a head start.

Here is the screenshot he's referring to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHRdn.jpg

The four content items: Our Issues, Our Contract, Opportunities, Q&A is what I'm trying to add.

Unfortunately I only got a partial explanation and am humbly asking for the community's help on achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the moderator said you can make other page and design it as you want and call it into your `header.php` . It's so simple just make your page by `.php` format witch it start with:

```
<?php
```

and ends with:

```
?>
```

then call it like this:

```
<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

or even you can call it by `functions.php` like this:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

Just remember to do not call `header` and `footer` into your page cause you no want double header into each other.

Comment: Thanks for the response Scott. I'm sure it's simple, but I'm not understanding your solution because I don't know PHP or the intricacies of Wordpress. I'll understand it better with a more layman explanation. Under the child theme, I've created a custom header template and applied a custom page template for the page in question. in the child theme. What do I do from there?

Comment: _The four content items: Our Issues, Our Contract, Opportunities, Q&A is what I'm trying to add._  you only need to make an HTML page include `<?php` and `?>` in the first and end of that then give the address of that file into your header with the codes i gave you above. the rest is just design your custom  page that you made. up to you want to just be that 4 links or what ever you want.   and if still you're confuse take a look at this page may help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: The four content items are generated from shortcodes. How would that work in a php file?

Comment: like this: <?php do_shortcode('short code name'); ?>